# Reverse Engineering XCode Broadcast for iPhone Network Search

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, multicast, mdns

XCode performs a request which tries to access iPhones located in same network. These iPhones were configured for remote deployment.

tcpdump is printing out that lines:

> 13:09:41.271644 IP 192.168.1.39.5353 > 224.0.0.251.5353: 0*- [0q]
> 6/0/2 (Cache flush) TXT "", PTR _apple-mobdev2._tcp.local., PTR
> 60:ff:45:ff:87:ff@fe80::62f4:45ff:fe01:87ff._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local.,
> PTR
> 60:ff:45:ff:87:ff@fe80::62f4:45ff:fe01:87ff._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local.,
> (Cache flush) A 10.11.128.37, (Cache flush) SRV
> device-60-ff-45-ff-87-ff.local.:32498 0 0 (272) 13:09:41.271646 IP6
> fe80::a8:fe84:f802:1fa5.5353 > ff02::fb.5353: 0*- [0q] 6/0/2 (Cache
> flush) TXT "", PTR _apple-mobdev2._tcp.local., PTR
> 60:ff:45:ff:87:ff@fe80::62f4:45ff:fe01:87ff._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local.,
> PTR
> 60:ff:45:ff:87:ff@fe80::62f4:45ff:fe01:87ff._apple-mobdev2._tcp.local.,
> (Cache flush) A 10.11.128.37, (Cache flush) SRV
> device-60-ff-45-ff-87-ff.local.:32498 0 0 (272)

**Question**

Is it possible to do such a request with command line tools like `dig` or `curl`?

**Notes**

For some reasons XCode is not able to access the iPhones but other tools like `ios-deploy` are.

At the moment I still need a XCode gui to perform the multicast request above and use `ios-deploy` for further communication.

Comment: `tcpreplay` could be an option to just replay stored packets.

Answer (score 0):

Since the packet is a broadcast on port 5353 (Bonjour) I'd suggest trying to reproduce the same query by running `tcpdump` whilst modelling the same query using the `dns-sd` command; maybe `dns-sd -B _apple-mobdev2._tcp local`?